# How do I get the HTTP response code from a successful React query?

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-query

How do I get the status code from a successful React query?

This is my custom hook:

```
const validateIban = async (accountId, encodedIban) => {
    await axios
        .post(`${CUSTOMER_PORTAL_API}/policy/accounts/${accountId}/iban/${encodedIban}`)
};

export function useValidateIban(accountId) {
    return useMutation(encodedIban => validateIban(accountId, encodedIban));
}
```

And this is where I use the hook with mutate:

```
const validateIbanQuery = useValidateIban(accountId)


validateIbanQuery.mutate(encodeURIComponent(iban), {
        onSuccess: () => {
          ******HERE I WANT THE STATUS CODE (204, 202 e.g.)******
        },
        onError: (error) => {
          if (error.response.status === 400) {
            ....
          }
          if (error.response.status === 403) {
            ....
          }
        }
      })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first parameter of the `onSuccess` callback is the `AxiosResponse`:

```js
axios.post("/api/data", { text }).then(response => {
  console.log(response.status)
  return response; // this response will be passed as the first parameter of onSuccess
});
```

```js
onSuccess: (data) => {
  console.log(data.status);
},
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 67059797/how-do-i-get-the-http-response-code-from-a-successful-react-query]

Comment: this leads to data is undefined :(

Comment: @btrautmann I didn't return the data when configuring `axios-mock-adapter`, it should be fixed now. You can simply return `axios.post(...)`